# shopify app (python)Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, api, requirejs, shopify

with the Shopify API for python

i am able to place the script tag in the (client's) store .

Problem is i am having two script tags among one is a Require.js.

store page's source code (client's store)

```
var urls = ["myjsfilewithrequire.js? shop=store.myshopify.com","mysecondfile.js?shop=store.myshopify.com"];
```

this is what gets loaded .

How can i make sure that one js is loaded completed (requre.js) before rest files are loaded .

Is this way of doing is right ? ( I have not tired yet )

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'myscriptfile.js';
document.head.appendChild(imported);


function load_data(){
    undone = true;
    while(typeof(window.myscriptfile.data)=="object" && undone){

any loop();}
```

I guess there must be any better way to do it .

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and solved it by using [almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond).

It's by the maintainer of RequireJS, and is a light-weight AMD loader. It can be compiled in to your optimized JS, and then included (as a ScriptTag) in your client's Shopify site.